# Rewrite Pandas Series, based on two other Pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, vector, iteration, series

I got 3 Pandas Series, each having the same indexes. Two of them only contain True/False values, while the 3rd contains numbers. Is it possible to change the values of the 1rd Series, if 2/3nd are both not True at the same time?

1st Pandas series

| Index | Values |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3453 |
| 2 | 8593 |

2nd Pandas Series

| Index | Values |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | True |
| 2 | False |

3rd Pandas Series

| Index | Values |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | True |
| 2 | True |

Trying to achieve this for 1st Series

1st Pandas series

| Index | Values |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3453 |
| 2 | 0 |

I tried iterating with for loops, but have been struggling to index all 3 series right.

Comment: What is the expected result ?

Answer (score 0):

if all your data tables have the same length and sorted by the same index try this :

```
first_data=pd.DataFrame({"index":[1,2],"values":[3453,8593]})
second_data=pd.DataFrame({"index":[1,2],"values":[True,False]})
third_data=pd.DataFrame({"index":[1,2],"values":[True,True]})
first_data["values"]*second_data["values"]*third_data["values"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can use [`pd.Series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) or [`pd.Series.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) to keep or mask out values according to some other boolean Series:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

N = 10

s1 = pd.Series(np.random.randint(1000, 10000, size=N))
s2 = pd.Series(np.random.randint(2, size=N, dtype=bool))
s3 = pd.Series(np.random.randint(2, size=N, dtype=bool))
```

Sample data (here shown as dataframe for convenience):

```
     s1     s2     s3
0  5003   True   True
1  7527  False  False
2  1637  False   True
3  4136   True  False
4  6079   True   True
5  6663  False   True
6  9371  False  False
7  2098  False   True
8  6692   True   True
9  7289  False   True
```

Solution:

```
out = s1.where(s2 & s3, other=0)
```

out:

```
0    5003
1       0
2       0
3       0
4    6079
5       0
6       0
7       0
8    6692
9       0
```